# select tag in html not displaying default value

Tags: html

I've used the select tag with these three options:

```
<select id="MySelect" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" style        = "float:right;">
<option selected value = "#">Select</option>
<option value = "<%=lnk_edit%>">Edit</option>
<option value = "<%=lnk%>">Delete</option>
</select>
```

where lnk_edit and lnk are the reference to the pages which should be reached when user selects one of these options.Now, the problem is that when I click "Edit" and then click the Back button from that page, the option displayed is "Edit" and not "Select" which is set as the default value and I want the value of "select" tag to be "Select" when it returns to this page.

What may be the reason for this? And what should I do to correct it?

Comment: Back does not setup the Dom all over again, it is pulled from the last state. (So it by design)
This should correct that
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
 <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
 <META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">

Comment: @juanvan No change in the result after adding the above code also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set Onload event in the `<BODY onload="fix_selects()">`

And use this java script

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
  function fix_selects(){
    document.getElementById("MySelect").selectedIndex = 0;
    //Or
    // document.getElementById("MySelect").value = '#';

  }
<script>
```